# change content of gridview dynamically

Tags: gridview, templatefield

I have a grid view with three bound field columns and a template filed column.
The template field column has three buttons (edit, view, and delete).
So every row has those three buttons.

How can I dynamically change the content of the grid view when the edit button is clicked?
Also delete a row when delete button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.
Firstly you need to populate the datagridview either in timer or thread.
Secondly, in order to edit/delete recordset you will have to use

private void DataGrid_ABC_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs gridmap)

private void DataGrid_ABC_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs gridmap)

public void DataGrid_ABC_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

for further info, feel free to get in touch.